# How to create a variant outlined for a FormGroup

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How can I create a variant outlined for a FormGroup of a checkbox components.

```
<FormGroup >
       <FormControlLabel label="a" control={<Checkbox />} />
       <FormControlLabel label="b" control={<Checkbox inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'primary checkbox' }} />} />
</FormGroup>
```

So when the user select a check box the color of the outline will change.

Something like:

```
<FormControl variant="outlined">
            <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">Age</InputLabel>
            <Select
                labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
                id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
                label="Age"
            >
                <MenuItem value="">
                    <em>None</em>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
```

Thank you

Comment: Add `variant='outlined'` in `Select` also.

Comment: Are you thinking something like a form `legend`?

Comment: technicallynick - yes